# Replace all #333 colors with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is how do I replace a certain color in javascript? I have a few SVG fills which I need to change in color but how exactly do I get all #333 colors that exist in my document?

Comment: Have you heard of hexadecimal colours?

Comment: @DominatorX yes I have.

Comment: @DominatorX Why do you ask?

Answer (score 1):

I would try something with jquery (going to be a good bit simpler than anything with pure js)

```
$(this).html().replace("#333","#f2f2f2")
```

Comment: I need to store this in a variable so I can use it in my function. Can I do: var colorFind = $("*").html().get("#333")

Comment: so basically using * to target all elements and .get to just get the colors

Comment: Yeah, you should be able to store it in a variable... I am not sure if * will get you what you want. It may, I am just not sure.  sorry for the slow response.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something you could do. This example would return all elements with that color.

```
var results = $('*').filter(function() {
     return $(this).css('color') == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g5yp1g7y/

You will notice I didn't use hex. The problem with selecting by hex is most browsers will convert the color style to rgb when you call them via JS.